# Angular mat-checkbox different border-colors for different checkboxes

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, styles

I need to change the border colors for the following checkboxes , one to green and other to red.

```
<div style="margin-left:30%;margin-top: 20%;">
    <mat-checkbox>Hello</mat-checkbox><br>
    <mat-checkbox>Hai</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to overrid specific checkbox border, you can override the class:

```
.mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: red; 
}
```

If you want to change checkbox color.
There is a color attribute.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwjynh

Comment: i am able to change the border color using the following.                                                     
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color:green;
}                                                                                                                                          
But i need to set two different colrs for two checkboxes.

Comment: have you checked the url sample, not only the border, the color of the checkbox is different

Comment: <mat-checkbox [color]="primary">Hello</mat-checkbox>     it is not working.

Comment: ...try color="primary" instead of [color]="primary"

Comment: Glad to hear that helps. Can you accept this as the answer?